# How to read words with ' in them?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got this code that prints the most common words of a txt file. I want it to print and count words with `'` in them. How can I do this?

```
words = open(input('Enter the name of the file: ')).read().lower().split()
number_of_words = int(input('Enter how many top words you want to see: '))
uniques = []
stop_words = ["a", "an", "and", "in", "is", "the"]
for word in words:
  check_special = False
  if word.isalnum():
    check_special = True
  if word not in uniques and word not in stop_words and check_special:
    uniques.append(word)

counts = []
for unique in uniques:
  count = 0
  for word in words:
    if word == unique:
      count += 1
  counts.append((count, unique))

counts.sort()
counts.reverse()

counts_dict = {count: [] for count, word in counts}
for count, word in counts:
    counts_dict[count].append(word)

count_num_word = 0
for count in counts_dict:
    if count_num_word >= number_of_words:
        break
    print('The following words appeared %d times each: %s' % (count, ', '.join(sorted(counts_dict[count]))))
    count_num_word += 1
```

Comment: Don't call `word.isalnum()`, since it will exclude words with punctuation in them.

Comment: If you want to exclude other punctuation, but allow `'`, you'll need to add a check that all the non-alphanumeric characters are `'`.

Comment: So instead of word.isalnum() what can I use? I'm new with python.

Answer (score 2):

Write your own function that checks whether every character in a string is alphanumeric or quote, and use that instead of `word.isalnum()`.

```
def alnum_or_quote(s):
    return all(c == "'" or c.isalnum() for c in s)
```

Then replace `if word.isalnum():` with `if alnum_or_quote(word):`